# how to save a dictionary on a file and then load it(working with json and files) - python

Tags: python

i want to take a dictionary from accounts.txt (its supposed to be a json) and add it key exc.author.id (its user id)

```
@bot.command()
async def register(exc):
    f=open("accounts.txt","r+")
    w=json.loads(f.read())
    w[exc.author.id]="some"
    f.writelines(w)
```

i am ALMOST secure the issue is on "f.writelines(w)"

error: Command raised an exception: TypeError: write() argument must be str, not int

Comment: FYI, `json.loads(f.read())` can be simplified to `json.load(f)`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the entire error message. Doing so will make this page more helpful to future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using `json.dump()` to write JSON back to the file. You also need to rewind so that you start writing at the beginning.

And after you write, you have to truncate it in case the new JSON is shorter than the original.

```
@bot.command()
async def register(exc):
    with open("accounts.txt","r+") as f:
        w=json.load(f)
        w[exc.author.id]="some"
        f.seek(0)
        json.dump(f)
        f.truncate()
```

Comment: whats f.truncate()? sorry im begginer

Comment: It removes everything from the file after the current point.

Comment: is there a way to simply list to file? it should be easyer

Comment: No, there's no way to update a JSON file in place.

Comment: For instance, if the file is originally `abcdefg` and you want to replace it with `1234`, you have to truncate after writing `1234`, otherwise you get `1234efg`

Comment: i know its not part of the question but ¿hoe can i save a object like imaobject(), json cant do it?

Comment: Look at the `pickle` module.

Comment: @WORMHACKER Please post a new question.

Comment: sorry i forget to mark this as correct